# enable PDO on server, or use laravel without?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, laravel, cpanel

i have laravel based cms, when i try to put it on our server it says:
**Class 'PDO' not found**

So i tried to just write a small script with just a new pdo object, same result.
The server doesnt belong to our company, so i dont have access to php.ini etc.
I have access to cpanel, but php options are only for reference there, i cant change them( dont see pdo in there anyways).

*I have to finish the cms, and make it work, but i m complete noob in servers-related stuff.* :(

I am right now at weekend, so cant call the support\etc for the server.
Is there anything i can do now to enable PDO?
i found an article on google how to enable it from cpanel whm, but it doesnt look like my cpanel at all.

p.s. is this usually a problem to get the server company enable extensions like pdo\mysqli\etc?
is this normal they only have basic mysql? seems very weird to me, its like basics for DB, and working with basic mysql only, which is much more prone to injections is simply not safe and costs x10 work hours to make programmers write own db class when there is great free stuff like pdo\mysqli...this is stupid as hell, for a PAID hosting...

Comment: Only having basic `mysql` usually means they haven't upgraded anything in a while (either to avoid 'breaking' customers' code by upgrading, or just a bit lazy). _Usually_, it is no problem to ask them to enable it & upgrade php etc, as `PDO` is kind of built-in. Enabling other pecl extensions, especially beta ones, can be more of a challenge depending on hoster.

Comment: PDO only works on PHP5, and only came installed from 5.1 onwards. For versions of PHP4 there was a class developed by someone that emulated PDO  http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2572-PHP-PDO-database-abstraction-interface-for-PHP-4.html - I used this in the transition period to develop PDO-ready code.

Comment: Some hosters lag, but as said, some by laziness, but some by choice: the last time I saw a PHP3 (!) install was about 4 years ago, and the client forbade an upgrade, as the perfectly working php3 code wasn't entirely compatible with php4... As a client, I also would expect the hoster to at least ask me first before an upgrade, and some switch it around to the client having to ask for an upgrade, which is quite fine.

Comment: Cups, they have php 5.3.23
how do i use this package? just import stuff in autoload?

Comment: imported that class, it can connect to db pretty much works etc, but laravel uses all kinds of stuff that still wont work, like for instance it doesnt know what pdo::fetch_class is...this is no substitute for normal pdo :(

Answer (score 0):

As you are having cPanel, The best and easy way is to enable the extension with easyapache

log in to server via ssh

> /scripts/easyapache

Don't forget to run that in screen

> screen -S test

Then enable the PDO extension for the php.

If you are not expert with easyapache back end, then try from WHM. here are the steps

- Login to WHM
- Click Apache Update
- Click Start Customizing Based on Profile
- Select an Apache version
- Click Next Step
- Select PHP 5
- Click Next Step
- Select a version of PHP 5
- Click Next Step
- Click Exhaustive Options List button
- Scroll down to the check box labeled PDO ( Two pdo Options to be checked )
- Click Save and Build

Both will work in the same way. I hope this will resolve your issue.

Comment: yes, i wrote, i saw this tutorial online when googled for solution, but in my cPanel's Software section i only have options to install chats\shopping carts, i have no access to real settings like this. thanks for reply though

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you. Are you on a shared environment? Otherwise you will have the root access hence the WHM or root shell access. If you are on a shared environment, you have to ask your hosting provider to enable the module :)

Comment: i did, its ok now :) they even disabled them damn magic functions! woo-hoo :)